# error applying string to notification title

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Basicly I'm tring to change "GCM Message" in `setContentTitle("GCM Message")` with R.string.myTitle and I get a:

```
setContentTitle (java.lang.CharSequence) in Builder cannot be applied to (int)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to do like

```
setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.Mytitle))
```